# How to convert script output files to text?

Tags: linux, debugging, text

I'm on Linux and my code produces lots of output (10 MB or more).  I save that output to a text file with the 'script' command like this

```
 > script -c MyCommand LOG_FILE
```

Then I want to search for errors with grep, but it thinks LOG_FILE is binary:

```
 > grep -i error LOG_FILE
   Binary file LOG_FILE matches
```

I don't understand.  I can run 'more' on LOG_FILE and it looks like text.  I can edit LOG_FILE with text editors and it looks like text.  What do I need to do to LOG_FILE so that I can grep for key phrase in it?

Comment: Can you supply a generated LOG_FILE ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot.  The file is tens of megabytes in size.

Answer (score 2):

Try the -a or --text option

```
   -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
```

Comment: Thank you.  'grep -a' solved my problems.